# I created a virtual environment in macos, and my global environment fails after installing some packages in the virtual one

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, jupyter-lab

I created a virtual environment in my macbook, and installed some packages using the following commands:

```
python3 -m venv virtenv1
source ~/virtenv1/bin/activate
pyenv install 3.9.7
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install jupyter lab
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=virtenv1kernel
```

My goal was to have a separate environment and use the setup for notebooks in jupyter lab.

Now two things happened:

1. the python version in the virtual environment is 3.7.6 (which is the version of my global), even when I specified pyenv install 3.9.7. This is not a big deal, but I didn't expect it.
2. When I try to use the command line for anything in my global, I get error:

   pyenv: version `3.7.13' is not installed (set by /Users/user/.pyenv/version)

I am not able to launch jupyter lab from my global environment anymore, I can do so only from the virtual one. Does anyone know what is going on and how can I fix it? Anything would be highly appreciated.

It seems that my original .pyenv file has changed, but I have attempted to restore it with `pip install pyenv 3.7.6` and the build fails.

I need to restore my previous setup, but I am not being successful in even identifying what went wrong and where, and I haven't been able to find anything online. I don't understand how changes in a virtual environment can affect the global one.

Edit: I managed to get my environment working again. It is not the correct version, but the packages in my jupyter kernel are and that is what I need. If someone ever bumps into this question and is able to offer any insight as of why or how this might have happened, your insight will still be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Python virtual environment with the `venv` module activate it using the `source [virtual env]/bin/activate` it effectively hardcodes the Python version to the *global* Python version that was invoked to create the virtual environment.

If you want to use a different Python version in the virtual environment and use `pyenv` to achieve this, you should first install the desired Python version globally and make sure your `python -m venv virtenv1` command uses the desired Python version.

I think another issue is that `pyenv install` installs but does not activate the specified version, you need to run a separate command to do that.

The following sequence will probably work although I haven't verified it on my machine:

```bash
pyenv install 3.9.7
pyenv shell 3.9.7
which python && python --version  # just to verify the exact Python version
python -m venv virtenv1
source virtenv1/bin/activate
which python && python --version
```